# RTMP to decklink output using FFMPEG results in eventual "crunchy" audio

Tags: ffmpeg, blackmagic

I'm using FFMPEG to take an RTMP stream and output it to a Decklink device.  Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.4:1935:/publish/internal -async 1 -r 60 -b:a 320k -aspect 16:9 -vf "scale=1920:-1:flags=bicubic" -f decklink -vcodec v210 "DeckLink Mini Monitor HD"
```

Occasionally (also randomly) the output will get what I can best describe as "crunchy" audio.  I see this error in the ffmpeg output:

```
Jan 02 22:47:36 kiri bash[505081]: [decklink @ 0x5653d27e0f00] There's no buffered audio. Audio will misbehave!
Jan 02 22:47:36 kiri bash[505081]: [decklink @ 0x5653d27e0f00] There are not enough buffered video frames. Video may misbehave!
```

I suspect this is due to a hiccup from the device sending the RTMP stream or the RTMP server, but I'd like to find a way to have ffmpeg handle this situation.  I was hoping that the `-async 1` flag would tell ffmpeg to speed up or slow down the audio to catch up to the video, but I still ran into issues doing this.

The full ffmpeg output is here:

```
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://192.168.1.4:1935:/publish/internal':
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1920
    displayHeight   : 1080
    fps             : 60
    profile         :
    level           :
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 6.508000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 8192 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 327 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> v210 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[decklink @ 0x563c7fb34440] Found Decklink mode 1920 x 1080 with rate 60.00
Output #0, decklink, to 'DeckLink Mini Monitor HD':
  Metadata:
    |RtmpSampleAccess: true
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 1920
    displayHeight   : 1080
    fps             : 60
    profile         :
    level           :
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: v210, yuv422p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 2654208 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 v210
  Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 pcm_s16le
```

Anybody have any ideas of what I can change with my command to better address this?